# String formatting inside string format

Tags: python, string

I face this peculiar situation:

I am using `str` format to give my filenames a certain pattern. For example I am using a prefix and then a fixed-length number to create the filename. The problem occurred when I needed to also control the fixed-length number length:

```
prefix = 'action1'
n = 6    
for i in range(0, 6):
    filename = '{}_{:06}.jpg'.format(prefix, i)
    print(filename)
```

> action1_000000.jpg
>   action1_000001.jpg
>   ...

I came up with this idea which combines old and new style string formatting but it's peculiar and surely prone to being deprecated:

```
n = 4    
for i in range(0, 6):
    filename = ('{}_{:0%d}.jpg' % n).format(prefix, i)
    print(filename)
```

> action1_0000.jpg
>   action1_0001.jpg
>   ...

So, is there any other approach to control the string format (the `:06` part) inside a string format (`{}_{:06}.jpg`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{}` inside `{}` in `str.format()`. Try this:

```
'{}_{:0{}}.jpg'.format(prefix, i, 4)
```

See at "*Nesting arguments and more complex examples*" at [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples)

Or, using the [f-string feature](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
prefix = 'action1'
n = 4
for i in range(0, 6):
    filename = f'{prefix}_{i:0{n}}.jpg'
    print(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use .rjust()?

```
prefix = 'action1_'
n = 6
counter = 1
filename = prefix + str(counter).rjust(n, '0')
print(filename)
```